# Is there any way to bind a alias for some IP without using DNS or hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh

In a local area network, there is no DNS service. I also have no permission to `sudo`.

In daily work, I frequently use SSH between some nodes. It is so troublesome to type `ssh user@192.168.1.2` every time.

Is there any other way to bind aliases to IPs and make my `SSH` more convenient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Host` stanza in your `~/.ssh/config` that calls it whatever you like. See the `ssh_config(5)` man page for details.

```
Host thatoverthere
  HostName 192.168.1.2
```

...

```
$ ssh user@thatoverthere
```